# libusb seems to fail under a class coding structure but works without one?

Tags: python, libusb, nxt

I have a simple working example using Python/NXT/libusb as follows (note: using Lego's NXT which has a USB interface):

```
import nxt.locator
from nxt.motor import *

def flip_cube(b):
   m_arm = Motor(b, PORT_B)
   m_arm.turn(75, 85)
   m_arm.turn(-50, 85)

b = nxt.locator.find_one_brick()
flip_cube(b)
```

Above works fine.

As a training exercise, I try to "objectize" the python code, so that I could start putting libraries around the code, but now the LibUSB library complains that it cant find the usb device.  Huh?  What am I doing wrong.  Here is my attempt of the code using a class structure:

```
import nxt.locator
from nxt.motor import *

class BasicRobotTestCase():
    __test__ = True

    def __init__(self):
        b = nxt.locator.find_one_brick()

    def flip_cube(self):
        m_arm = Motor(b, PORT_B)
        m_arm.turn(75, 85)
        m_arm.turn(-50, 85)

    def test_flip_cube(self):
        flip_cube()
```

When I execute the above, I get the following error (even though if I re-execute the first sample, again it executes fine):

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: USBError (No such device (it may have been disconnected))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/nose-0.11.4-py2.6.egg/nose/loader.py", line 485, in makeTest
    return self._makeTest(obj, parent)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/nose-0.11.4-py2.6.egg/nose/loader.py", line 539, in _makeTest
    return MethodTestCase(obj)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/nose-0.11.4-py2.6.egg/nose/case.py", line 331, in __init__
    self.inst = self.cls()
  File "/Users/gnunez/git-projects/pdca_automation/rubics/tests/basic_robot_test_case.py", line 8, in __init__
    b = nxt.locator.find_one_brick()
  File "/Users/gnunez/git-projects/pdca_automation/nxt/locator.py", line 112, in find_one_brick
    for s in find_bricks(host, name, silent, method):
  File "/Users/gnunez/git-projects/pdca_automation/nxt/locator.py", line 43, in find_bricks
    for s in socks:
  File "/Users/gnunez/git-projects/pdca_automation/nxt/usbsock.py", line 83, in find_bricks
    for bus in usb.busses():
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/usb/legacy.py", line 330, in busses
    return (Bus(),)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/usb/legacy.py", line 326, in __init__
    self.devices = [Device(d) for d in core.find(find_all=True)]
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/usb/legacy.py", line 311, in __init__
    self.configurations = [Configuration(c) for c in dev]
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/usb/core.py", line 706, in __iter__
    yield Configuration(self, i)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/usb/core.py", line 407, in __init__
    configuration
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/usb/_debug.py", line 52, in do_trace
    return f(*args, **named_args)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/usb/backend/libusb10.py", line 423, in get_configuration_descriptor
    config, byref(cfg)))
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/usb/backend/libusb10.py", line 357, in _check
    raise USBError(_str_error[retval.value])
USBError: No such device (it may have been disconnected)
```

Comment: Does the original code still work? (e.g. is this *actually* the code causing the problem, or just a coincidence?)

Comment: Yes, the original still works - every time!  I run the original code, the USB is found and functions.  I run the new "class" structured code, it cannot find the USB.  I go back and run the original code, and again it find the USB and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you create your BasicRobotTestCase, you lose the b variable if you don't store it as a member of your instance (ie `self.b`)

**EDIT:** well, the missing `self` weren't the origin of the problem, maybe the way nose instanciate your class change something to the USB grabbing, try to instanciate the class directlry.

```
import nxt.locator
from nxt.motor import *

class BasicRobotTestCase():
    __test__ = True

    def __init__(self):
        self.b = nxt.locator.find_one_brick()   # Store the brick in self.b

    def flip_cube(self):
        m_arm = Motor(self.b, PORT_B)   # use the stored brick in self.b to create the motor
        m_arm.turn(75, 85)
        m_arm.turn(-50, 85)

    def test_flip_cube(self):
        self.flip_cube()

if __name__=="__main__":
    BasicRobotTestCase().test_flip_cube()
```

Comment: Rats!  I hate it when a simple typo distracts from the original problem - sorry about that.  That missing self was a simple typo when I minimized the code to post.  The problem is not the storing of the variable/object - the problem is that nxt.locator.find_one_brick() fails to find the USB device

Comment: [trying again]  Rats!  I hate it when a simple typo distracts from the original problem - sorry about that. That missing self was a simple typo when I minimized the code to post.<br/>The problem is not the storing of the variable/object - the problem is that nxt.locator.find_one_brick() fails to find the USB device and has nothing to store, failing when in a class structure, but working fine when NOT in a class structure.  It seems odd that a class structure code approach would cause a problem?<br/>Just as sanity check, I tried the "self" changes provided with no luck.

Comment: @George Nunez : oh. And if you use your class outside from nose ? with a `if __name__ == "__main__": BasicRobotTestCase().test_flip_cube()` ?

Comment: Wow, it does appear to be nosetests.  I tried as you suggested, but it still did not find the USB.  I thought you were on the right track, though, in regards to nosetests (nice observation by the way), so I used the same class structure, but used straight python (without nosetests), and that worked fine.  So something that nosetests is doing is causing the libUSB to fail - I suspect that nosetests is finding some other libUSB that is not configured correctly or something.  THANK YOU!